# como enviar un resultado de una funcion javascript a php

Tags: php, javascript

```
function onQtyChange(e) {
  var row = this.parentNode.parentNode;
  var cellPrice = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(5)');
  var prevPrice = parseFloat(row.getAttribute('data-price'));
  var newQty = parseFloat(this.value);
  alert(prevPrice);
  var total = prevPrice * newQty;
  cellPrice.innerText = '$' + total;


}
```

esto es lo que quiero hacer con el de php

```
  $sumador_total=0;
  $total = ;
  $precio_total_f=number_format($total,2);//Precio total formateado
  $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
  $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador

  $subtotal=number_format($sumador_total,2,'.','');
  $total_iva=($subtotal * 12 )/100;
  $total_iva=number_format($total_iva,2,'.','');
  $total_factura=$subtotal+$total_iva;
```

Comment: Tienes que usar ajax

Comment: tambien te recomiendo a nivel solo visual lo haga javascript, pero a nivel de guardado que lo haga php , conozco historias donde le cambiaban los valores al javascript y guardaba y pagaban esa cantidad

Comment: alguien me pude desir coo lo puedo hacer con ajax

Answer (score 0):

//Puedes usar ajax de Jquery

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: "miURL.php",
    data: {parametro1: "valor1", parametro2: "valor2"}
}).done(function (resp) {
    console.log("Servidor: ", resp);
}).fail(function (err) {
    console.log("Ocurrio un error", err)
}).always(function() {
    console.log("Ajax Terminado");
});
```

// Desde tu servidor php

```
<?php

$parametro1 = $_POST["parametro1"];
$parametro2 = $_POST["parametro2"];

echo json_encode(Array("parametro" => $parametro1));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

recuerda que javascript es un lenguaje que trabaja por el lado del cliente, por lo cual la forma mas fácil de poder guardar algún parámetro a php (trabaja por el lado del servidor) es por medio de:

> ajax

realizando una petición al servidor para poder ser ejecutada

ejemplo practico:

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

añado link de referencia de api : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/